# cpprestsdk request blocked and response with "Failed to read HTTP status line" in a multi-threaded situation

Tags: multithreading, c++11, cpprest-sdk

I have created a client server system server by following the `CppRestSdk` examples.

Here is the sample code section of my implementation (only the request sending section).

```
nf.request(methods::POST, U("/"), requestBody)
    .then([=] (pplx::task<http_response> task)
    {
        LOG_ENTRY;
        // some other work ..
        resp = task.get(); // fails
        http_response resp;
        do {
            try {

                resp = task.get();
            } catch (std::exception& e) {
                higLog("EXCEPTION CAUGHT: %s", e.what());

            }

            // some other checks ..

        }while(0);

       // process resp later ..

    }
```

where `nf` is a `http_client`.

Here is the architecture of my system.

[image: architecture]

[image: thread_pool_call_flow]

The main thread runs an `epoll` loop in the `front-end` server. It also creates an explicit `thread-pool`. The `epoll` loop receives the incoming messages from the client side and stores those messages in a work_queue (implemented by me). One of the threads (pool size of `500`) in the thread pool wakes up and picks a `job` from the work queue. This thread performs processing on the message and talks to `back-end` server using cpprestsdk `http_client` object.

For a small number (`10` or `15`) of concurrent threads in the client side, the system works fine. But when I increase the number of threads (`50` threads for example) int the client side, the `front-end` server starts showings unpredictable errors. Mostly it blocks for a long time in the task.get() function. Sometimes it also shows "Failed to read HTTP status line" int he catch block.

I am new to `cpprestsdk`. I am not sure what is happening really. But to my guess `backlog queue size` is small in the `back-end` server. I found a `set_backlog()` function, but I can not use it because of const reference. 
[line 307](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/blob/master/Release/include/cpprest/http_listener.h).

What could be the reason for the above errors? It is common behavior? Is it because of `40` threads inside `cpprestsdk thread pool` ?

Comment: That reads like a scaling issue of the server. How many concurrent requests your server can handle i.e. `epoll`? And, how are they being processed? Added latency during processing? Did you do some kind of benchmark or load testing use a tool e.g. `Apache Bench`, SoapUI, etc.?

Comment: No benchmark. I am using my own load-test program on the client side. The server can handle 10 threads with the server using `thread pool`. Without `thread-pool` server can handle `100+` client threads(i.e. server is having only one main threads + `40 cpprestsdk` threads).

Comment: Are you sure the sdk is thread safe? Checked the whole documentation, FAQ and their issue tracker?
Gone by the open issue count, this library real seems to have problems.